# What layout to use when wanting to display over 10,000 textviews(Strings)

Tags: layout, android-listview, grid-layout

[Image below is what iv constructed already, but can see the daunting task of creating it for 40 students with 250-300 entires each...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRJGz.png)What layout would i use if i was to display over 10000 textviews(strings)?

Think of it as a table where there are 40 student names down the side of the xml layout and each of these students had its own row. In that row it displayed them being absent or present with the letter A(Absent) and P(Present).

I need each student to have at least 250 entries or textviews for the school calandar year. So as you can see 250 entries multiplied by 40 students equals alot of individual textviews which is not ideal.

I am stuck on which layout to use; ListView, GridView or is there another easier layout to display all this data that is being passed from another class using the spinners of each student? So every time a user pushes the confirm button from the class with the spinners it will take that string and pass onto the class that i want to display it.  Like a roll book for school. Thanks

Comment: A [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) might be an option here.  But I suspect any layout will be rather inefficient here, so maybe you better do without any layout at all and draw it on your own using a plain canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... iv attached an image to show what iv done to date and what i looking at doing...

Comment: maybe a list view row for each student? is this possible and in each row it gets broken into 300 sections to display the individual strings for each student...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget layouts here.  Better draw [everything completely on your own](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html).  It may be a bit more work, but you have complete control over what's going on, you don't need any XML, and you avoid surprises with the sometimes funny, sparsely documented behavior of those layouts.  As a start, you create your own View class and implement a few functions:

```
public class UiView extends View {
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {/*...*/}
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {/*...*/}
}
```

and put it into your main layout:

```
<com.mytool.UiView ...
```

Then you have complete freedom to tune the behavior by implementing `onDraw` and `onTouchEvent`.